# In Nagios, how can I have a contact that only gets one notification for each failure?

Tags: nagios

I have what I believe is a common Nagios setup: when a host or service has a problem, it sends an email to the on-call person and then continues sending emails every hour until the problem is acknowledged or goes away on its own.

I would now like to feed problems (and resolutions, etc.) into a logging system and I don't want to see the hourly "service is still broken" messages.  I just want to see the initial, "Service is broken," followed (maybe) by, "Problem is acknowledged", followed eventually by, "Service is OK."  (Specifically, I'm logging to a Slack channel, but I don't think that detail will make a difference to the solution.)

Is there an easy way to set up a "log" contact that will get a notification for the first service or host failure, but not the repeating ones?

One theoretically-possible way to do this is through escalations.  Here's an example for service notifications:

```
define serviceescalation {
    host_name            *
    service_description  *

    contacts  slack

    first_notification  1
    last_notification   1
    escalation_options  w,c,u
}
define serviceescalation {
    host_name            *
    service_description  *

    contacts  slack

    first_notification  1
    last_notification   0
    escalation_options  r
}
```

Unfortunately, that only gets warning, critical, unknown, and recovery notifications.  I would also like to log flapping and downtime notifications, which don't appear to be passed through the escalation system at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could enable syslog logging in the main config file, and then use a tool like [syslack](https://github.com/lavab/syslack), [log-to-slack](https://github.com/kokarn/log-to-slack), or similar to send to Slack.

Also, as you suspected/hinted-at, you can do this via host/service escalations applied to hostgroups, servicegroups, and/or using wildcards.

The [Time-Saving Tricks docs page](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objecttricks.html) shows some ways escalations can be applied broadly.

You could also write a custom notification script (often the solution for complex notification requirements), or use an [event handler](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/eventhandlers.html) (if you need even more flexibility).

Comment: The wildcard in escalation definitions was what I needed to easily apply escalations to everything easily, but I then learned that flapping and downtime notifications don't get escalated, so it looks like that won't work for me.  (I'll edit my question to reflect that.)  I might need to go outside the notification system; I'll look into log parsing.

Answer (score 0):

As long I didn't misunderstand the question, you may want to look at the object definitions of hosts and services:

[Host Definition](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html#host)

You can set the *notification_interval* value to 0, Nagios will call the *x_notification_commands* when a Service or an Host leave the HARD state.

Template example:

```
define host{
notification_interval 0
...
_log_level 1
register 0
}
```

You can even play around with custom variables, to set your own log levels here.

Comment: My problem is that I want the on-call person to continue getting hourly notifications, so I need a nonzero `notification_interval` for that.  I want Slack to get only the initial and recovery notifications in addition to the usual behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just write a custom notification command script for the contact? Then you can parse the message flows using macros anyway you wish.

```
define contact{
        name                            log-contact
        service_notification_period     24x7
        host_notification_period        24x7
        service_notification_options    w,u,c,r,f,s
        host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s
        service_notification_commands   logger-notify-service
        host_notification_commands      logger-notify-host
        register                        0
        }
```